# How to delete a document in a collection in Firebase/Firestore using its id?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page in my application(in angular) where the user can post a comment. 
The comment is stored in Firestore collection with the name of "comments". The user should be able to delete the comment once he clicks the delete button next to it.

My **comments.component.ts file** code is as below -

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

@Component({
selector: 'app-comments',
templateUrl: './comments.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./comments.component.css']
})
export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {

comment : string;
allcomments : any[]=[];
@Input('postId') postId : string;
cid : any;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(){

this.getComments();

}

postComment(){
firebase.firestore().collection("comments").add({
comment : this.comment,
post: this.postId,
owner: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
ownerName : firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

}).then((data) =>{
 // console.log(data);
 this.getComments();
 console.log("commID",data.id);
 this.cid = data.id;

 }).catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error)
 })
}

getComments(){

this.allcomments = [];
firebase.firestore().collection("comments")
.where("post","==",this.postId)
.orderBy("created","desc")
.get().then((data)=>{

  data.docs.forEach((commentRef)=>{
  this.allcomments.push(commentRef.data())

  })

})
.catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error)
})

}

onDelete(){

 //console.log("INSIDE DELETE")
 console.log(this.cid)
 firebase.firestore().collection("comments").doc(this.cid).delete()
 .then(()=>{

  console.log("DELETED")
 }).catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error)
 });

}
}
```

The delete function takes cid as null. My question is, how can I pass the correct comment id of the comment I am trying to delete to the onDelete() function ?

I am a beginner. Please excuse me if this sounds trivial.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: is this null `console.log("commID",data.id);`?  How are you calling `postComment()`?

Comment: I am calling that function on click of a button (i.e. Add comment button in my html file )
And console.log("commID",data.id) is giving me the correct document id in which the comment is saved.

Comment: are u deleting after posting? You are only getting the id after posting, so if you are deleting on load of the page then it will be null

Comment: No, there is separate button to delete the comment which calls the onDelete() function on click. Do I have to bind some property or something ?

Comment: ```this``` is referring to the function not to the element, if you create new comment you can add the Firestore ID in a property of your HTML element, to delete the comment you need to pass that ID or the Selector of HTML element and get the ID of the comment, For example Stackoverflow append the ID of the comment in the ID of the HTML element ```#comment-110258985```

Comment: @JAHDZP Sorry, I did not understand completely. This is my HTML line of code -<button class="btn btn-danger card-link btn-sm float-right"
            (click)="delete()">
What should I add? Can you please help?

Comment: you need to pass the ID of the comment as parameter for the function delete

```<button class="btn btn-danger card-link btn-sm float-right" (click)="delete(comment.ID)"> ``` 

I found an example in the angular documentation

https://angular.io/guide/user-input#put-it-all-together

Comment: @JAHDZP Yes, I have tried that. It requires to pass the value of comment id in the .ts file as well. After I did, doc(cid) got value of cid ( which is comment id) as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should work to delete a document from the collection.

```
this.firestore
  .collection('comments')
  .doc(commentId)
  .delete()
  .then(res => {
     console.log('Product deleted Successfully');
   })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.error('Error removing document: ', error);
  });
```